# Can you ID this stove/cooker?

Tags: stove

Make is SAUTER, It's white and the cooker operates with gas

### The problem

I want to bake pizza.

I don't know what are the different modes for the oven knob (the two knobs on the left are the temperature knob and the 'operation' mode), as all of the writings are erased by now (it's kind of old).

Experimenting with it could be hazardous and time consuming and a users manual could help clear this out.

Pizza means the oven should only generate heat from the bottom and I'm having trouble finding the correct position for the knob :)

### What I've tried

Googling for starters, but it's old and hard to find, I've tried playing with the knob, but that did not work well.
I looked behind / inside the bottom shelf and there is no sticker that describes what's the make/model etc

[image]
[image]

Comment: Have you looked on the back of it?

Answer (score 1):

The closest I could find for a manual was here: https://www.manual.guru/brands-6/SAUTER/4-oven/en-english-language.html

My guess, based on the icons shown here:

[image]

1. Clock
2. Clock Set (Hours and Minutes probably on different collars)
3. Oven Temperature Set
4. Grill + Lower Heating Element Set

   - See also: http://www.which.co.uk/reviews/built-in-ovens/article/oven-symbols-and-controls
5. Front Left Stovetop Set
6. Back Left Stovetop Set
7. Back Right Stovetop Set
8. Front Right Stovetop Set
9. Oven Fan
10. Oven Lamp

Comment: Thanks! But I know what's the purpose of each knob. The problem I'm having is the lack of symbols around knob no. 4. It has 5 different positions and I don't know what each position does and that's what i'm trying to find out...

Comment: My GE electric oven has two broiler settings Lo and Hi. It looks like yours has 5 different settings. Is the bottom drawer a broiler or is the broiling done in the main oven compartment?

Comment: @JimStewart The bottom shelf is a storage compartment

Comment: Does the broiler function work? If the broiler flames are visible, then you should be able to observe the effects of changing the setting on knob 4.

Comment: I Believe knob 4 is the broiler, Easy to test and find out. The triangles represent the heating element and  the rectangle   represents, *possibly*,  whatever is being broiled.   Can the knob be set to more then one position? Many ovens have  Hi and a Low broiler settings.